# How can I move up a <div> using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Q1**

How can I move the background image `<div class="hero"></div>` up so the image is under the navigation bar using bootstrap.

I have tried using `float` and `display: flex`.However, it doesn't seem to work.

**Site code**

```css
<style>
      .body {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      color: black;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      height: 10vh;
      z-index: 100;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      text-align: right;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      }
      .dropdown-menu li {
      text-align: center;
      }
      .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      .dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
      color: white;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14pt;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: black;
      border-radius: 9px;
      transition: all .2s;
      }
      .nav.navbar-nav,
      .nav.navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
      .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      }
      .section {
      min-height: 100vh;
      }
      .one {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      .two {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      #sections .section {
      padding-top: 50px;
      }
      .hero {
      background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/38892/pexels-photo-38892.jpeg") center center no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 60%;
      }
      .shape {
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: #4D5061;
      content: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
      color: white;
      height: 300px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 300px;
      top: 15%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -150px;
      z-index: 10;
      }
      .fa-angle-down {
      color: #0000;
      bottom: 0px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .fa-angle-up {
      color: #0000;
      bottom: 0px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .s1-text {
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      z-index: 99;
      font-size: 18pt;
      }
      .s2-text {
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      z-index: 99;
      font-size: 18pt;
      }
      .nav-text {
      font-size: 14pt;
      }
   </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/logo1_zpsep8qps5m.png"><img src="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/logo1_zpsep8qps5m.png" alt="Logo design"></a>
               <h1 class="nav-title centre-block">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Unit 6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#section3">Unit 14</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Unit 7</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Unit 1</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">CV</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Education</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <div id="sections">
         <div class="section one">
            <div class="shape"></div>
            <div class="hero"></div>
            <h1 class="s1-text center-block">WELCOME TO MY</h1>
            <h1 class="s2-text center-block">PORTFOLIO</h1>
            <a href="#section two"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
         </div>
         <section id="contact-me" class="section two">
            <a href="#section one"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
      </div>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#sections').fullpage();
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to add the background image to the whole section one. just try this--add the hero class to your `class="section one"`. Don't add margin.

**snippet**

```css
<style>
      .body {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      color: black;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      height: 10vh;
      z-index: 100;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      text-align: right;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      }
      .dropdown-menu li {
      text-align: center;
      }
      .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      .dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
      color: white;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14pt;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: black;
      border-radius: 9px;
      transition: all .2s;
      }
      .nav.navbar-nav,
      .nav.navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      }
      .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
      .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      }
      .section {
      min-height: 100vh;
      }
      .one {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      .two {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      #sections .section {
      padding-top: 50px;
      }
      .hero {
      background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/38892/pexels-photo-38892.jpeg") center center no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 60%;
      }
      .shape {
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: #4D5061;
      content: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
      color: white;
      height: 300px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 300px;
      top: 15%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -150px;
      z-index: 10;
      }
      .fa-angle-down {
      color: #0000;
      bottom: 0px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .fa-angle-up {
      color: #0000;
      bottom: 0px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .s1-text {
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      z-index: 99;
      font-size: 18pt;
      }
      .s2-text {
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      z-index: 99;
      font-size: 18pt;
      }
      .nav-text {
      font-size: 14pt;
      }
   </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/logo1_zpsep8qps5m.png"><img src="http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/logo1_zpsep8qps5m.png" alt="Logo design"></a>
               <h1 class="nav-title centre-block">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Unit 6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#section3">Unit 14</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Unit 7</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Unit 1</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">CV</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Education</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <div id="sections">
         <div class="section one hero">
            <div class="shape"></div>
            
            <h1 class="s1-text center-block">WELCOME TO MY</h1>
            <h1 class="s2-text center-block">PORTFOLIO</h1>
            <a href="#section two"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
         </div>
         <section id="contact-me" class="section two">
            <a href="#section one"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>
      </div>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#sections').fullpage();
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out now and add this to the other post you answered.